# Getting & displaying the highest score & names from an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

i am new to programming, and to java. I couldnt figure out how arraylist works.
Here are my current code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class test3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name,gender;
        int score;
        ArrayList<String> nameArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> scoreArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> genderArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter name: ");
            name =  input.next();
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("Enter Score: ");
                score = input.nextInt();   
                System.out.print("Gender: ");
                gender = input.next();
                System.out.println("");
                genderArray.add(gender);       
                scoreArray.add(score);
                nameArray.add(name);
            }
        }
        ///After Quitting loop, how to display the highest score & the names?
    }
}
```

After quitting the loop, i need the program to get and display the highest score along with the names and gender. I couldnt figure out how to do this with arraylist.

Example of what i want the code to output

> Enter name: Alfred
>  Enter Score: 60
>  Gender: Male
>
> Enter name: Tina
>  Enter Score: 86
>  Gender: Female
>
> Enter name: Ben 
>  Enter Score: 95 
>  Gender: Male
>
> Enter name: q
>  Highest score is Ben, with a score of 95, is a Male.

Sorry if i dont explain my question well, if anyone could help i would be gratefull!
Thanks

Comment: You can get the highest by sorting or just with a loop in `scoreArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation has a fundamental problem, information about a person is scattered in 3 different lists. This example will only be useful for practice. The real world implementation should organize related details in a class as the following.

```
class Person {
   String name;
   Integer score;
   String gender;
   ......
}
```

For this particular case, you can find the index of `max` and use the index to find the others.

> ///After Quitting loop, how to display the highest score & the names?

```
Integer maxScore = Collections.max(scoreArray);
Integer index = scoreArray.indexOf(maxScore );
gender = genderArray.get(index);
name = nameArray.get(index);
System.out.println("Highest score is" + name + ", with a score of " +maxScore  + ", is a " +  gender);
```

**OR**
If you would like to do it by your self(not to use `Collections.max()`), add a method to find the max as:

```
private int getMax(List<Integer> list) {
  int max = list.get(0);
  for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if(max < list.get(i)) {
      max = list.get(i);
    }
  } 
  return max;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i am totaly new at this, i am kind of aware how inefective my code was, as i currently only know most of the basic stuff. I am currently only trying to make something that "Works", i will try to correct the structure of my code at the end. Thanks for the  tips and explanation!

Answer (score 2):

It's better to create a class to store information for every person

```
class Person {
   String name;
   Integer score;
   String gender;
   // constructor, getter, setter
}
```

And create an ArrayList of Person

```
ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can add in the list after taking input in loop

```
list.add(new Person(name, score, gender));
```

You can use `Collections.max` with a comparator to get the max scored Person information

```
Person maxScoredPerson = Collections.max(list, Comparator.comparing(Person::getScore));
```

Comment: i havent learn about using constructor/getter setter method, will try to! thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way of doing it.

Find the index of the maximum element, assuming input is entered in parallel, get the index of the maximum element and then get the corresponding objects from other lists:

```
int max = Collections.max(scoreArray);
int index = scoreArray.indexOf(max);
gender = genderArray.get(index);
name = nameArray.get(index);

System.out.println("Highest score is "+name+", with a score of "+max+", is a "+gender);
```